# How do I put a Header and Footer on the first page of a letter?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

So the header and footer works on every other page but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it on the first page. This is all I have that isn't just text related.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\fancyhead[R]{Kalos Health Gold Plus Plan\\
2424 Niagara Falls Blvd\\
Niagara Falls, NY 14304 \\
www.kaloshealth.org}

\fancyfoot[L]{H3227001\_C02\_4b\_CFRMENROLL}

\begin{document}
\par
<MemberID>\\
<RxID>\\
<RxBin>\\
<RxPCN>\\

Dear <Name of Member>,\\
Thank you for enrolling in <plan name>. Medicare has approved your enrollment in <plan name> beginning <effective date>.\\

\bf{How will this plan work?}\\
\rm
Beginning <effective date>, you must see your <plan name> doctor(s) for your health care. This means that starting <effective date>, all of your health care, except emergency or urgently needed care, or out-of-area dialysis services, must be given or arranged by a <plan name> doctor(s). You will need to pay your plan co-payments and co-insurance at the time you get health care services, as provided in your member materials.Please remember that, except for emergency or out-of-area urgent care, or out-of-area dialysis services, if you get health care services from a non-<Plan Name> doctor without prior authorization, you will have to pay for these services yourself. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing the problem? It should begin with ``\documentclass{...}`` and end with ``\end{document}``. If I just add ``\begin{document} \end{document}`` to your code, the header and the footer both appear on the first (and only) page of the output, so something else must be causing the problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to make it into code in the box up there but, when I tried what you just said it works but then I go back to the original it doesn't work. The header and footers only appear on the second page.

Comment: The example you posted does produce the header and the footer if the line ``\pagestyle{fancy}`` is added. If it does not work in your original document, something else is producing the error, and without an example, it is hard to tell what it is. Is there a ``\thispagestyle{empty}`` or ``\thispagestyle{plain}`` on the first page?

Comment: So to my happiness and joy the header and footer are now on the first page but a new small error has popped up. Where the first line of text appears above the header line.

Comment: @DoofirthJr: You are probably also getting some warning in your `.log` that says something about `\headheight`... can you confirm this?

Comment: I have a "LaTex Error: Environment letter undefined" and two "Underfull \hbox (badness 10,000)"